# How to keep only three letters in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep, cut, tr

I'm accepting user input, $1, asking for a date.  People can't use the help page, so I'm forced to dumb it down when passing it through grep.

My input is Day-Mon-Year - where the day doesn't have a preceding 0 and the month is only 3 letters long.

I have everything done, except for the 3 letter 'cut-down.'

```
## stripping leading zero, turning words to lower-case & then capitalizing only the first letter ##
fdate=$(echo $1 | sed 's/^0//g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")
```

Can anyone help me take "August," for example, and cut it down to Aug, in this single variable?  Or perhaps another way?  I'm open to anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `m="August"; m="${m:0:3}"; echo "$m"`

Comment: I can't overlook the irony of asking a question, about people who can't use the help page, that could be answered by reading the `bash` man page.

Comment: @chepner, quite the reddit response and equally as helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in bash, without external commands:

```
a='0heLLo wOrld'
a=${a#0}     # Remove leading 0. Change to ${a##0} to remove multiply zeros
a="${a:0:3}" # Take 3 first characters
a=${a,,}     # Lowercase
a=${a^}      # Uppercase first
printf "%s\n" "$a" # Hel
```

Alternative it can be done in one `sed` command:

```
% sed 's/^0//;s/\(.\)\(..\).*/\u\1\L\2/' <<< "0heLLo wOrld"
Hel
```

Breakdown

```
s/^0//;                   # Remove leading 0. Change to 's/^0*//' to remove multiply zeros
s/
  \(.\)\(..\)             # Capture first character in \1 and next two in \2
             .*           # Match rest of string
               /\u\1\L\2/ # Uppercase \1 and lowercase \2
```

Comment: Helpful for the overall schooling in sed --- though, this is expecting the first 3 to always be the ones needed; what I was looking for, is something that takes the first three letters seen, period.  So, it could be January-2016 where it needs to take Jan ... or 04-July-2015 where it needs to take Jul.  Any magic for that?  Thanks again.

Comment: @TJO That's a completely different question. You should invest a little more time into crafting your questions so misunderstandings like this doesn't happen :-)

Comment: I read it multiple times as to be clear and gave examples - I guess i just can't be clear enough for all :-\  Like I had said, it's requesting user input for a date.  It could be any month -- and regardless of what's given as user input, if there are letters, I just want to keep 3.  I'll give your most recent comment a shot in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: You can split input to three variables: `IFS="-" read -r date month year <<< "04-July-2015"; echo "${month:0:3}" # Jul`